# TextGeometry not displaying, Could anyone tell me why?

Tags: javascript, three.js

**I have the following Three.js code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/optimer_regular.typeface.js"></script>
       <script>
           //Basic Three components
           var scene = new THREE.Scene();
           var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,       0.1, 1000 );

           var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
           renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
           document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
           //Let´s add a cube
           var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
           var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
           var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
           scene.add( cube );

           camera.position.z = 5;
           //Let´s add a text
           var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
               color: 0x00ff00
           });
           var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Sitescope', {
               font: 'optimer',
               weight: 'normal' 
           });
           var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeom, material2 );
           scene.add( textMesh );
           //Render scene
           function render() {
               requestAnimationFrame( render );
               cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
               cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
               renderer.render( scene, camera );
           }
           render();
       </script>
   </body>
```

When i run my code, My cube renders well but my text does not appear anywhere. 
The only output that i get in the javascript console is:
THREE.WebGLRenderer 69.

Could anyone tell me why my text does not appear? (I am a beginner in Three.js) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` you need a light in the scene. Otherwise the model will come out black. If your scene background is also black you will never know if the model was drawn or not. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/264jawhe/). I am using `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()`. Replace it with PhongMaterial to see what I am talking about. You can see the text is being drawn with black color just because it is over the green cube.

Comment: Thanks for your answer gaitat, i replaced THREE.MeshPhongMaterial() with THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() like you did it in the fiddle, but my text is not displayed yet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does your code differ from the fiddle? New fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/264jawhe/1/

Comment: I noticed that the difference is in the camera.position.set arguments. When i use your values, then the text is displayed but not the cube.

Comment: Your cube is too small. Change it to size 100,100,100